# Django Session Not Working - New Cart For Each Item

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working on a simple e-commerce site (following the [Coding for Entrepreneurs](https://www.udemy.com/coding-for-entrepreneurs/) course). I have view for the cart (below). I'm having a problem with the session - each time I add an item to the cart it gets added to a new cart, when they should be all added to the same cart for that session. I'm new to Django, and can't see where I'm going wrong here. Any advice on how to get each item added to go into the same cart would be much appreciated.

```
# imports

def add_to_cart(request):
    try:
        cart_id = request.session('cart_id')
    except Exception:
        # If cart_id doesn't exist, make one
        cart = Cart()
        cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id
        cart_id = cart.id

    # If adding to the cart, need to POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get data from the form
        form = ProductQtyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product_slug = form.cleaned_data['slug']
            product_quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            # Use that info to set up new objects in our cart
            try:
                product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
            except Exception:
                product = None
            try:
                cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
            except Exception:
                cart = None
            new_cart = CartItem(cart=cart, product=product, quantity=product_quantity)
            new_cart.save()
            print new_cart.product, new_cart.quantity, new_cart.cart # Check items are being added to the cart
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/')
        # If form is not valid, go to contact page
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't catch the generic `Exception`, catch the specific `KeyError` you're looking for.

Here, you'll get a `TypeError` because `cart_id = request.session('cart_id')` should use `[]` and not `()`. You're therefore entering your `except` clause, causing you to create a new cart when you didn't mean to.

You should do:

```
try:
    cart_id = request.session['cart_id'] # Fix this
except KeyError:                         # Fix that
    # If cart_id doesn't exist, make one
    cart = Cart()
    cart.save()
    request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id
    cart_id = cart.id
```

But anyway, is the cart not existing really an "exceptional" condition? Probably not. So you might want to do:

```
cart_id = request.session.get('cart_id')

if cart_id is None:
    cart = Cart.objects.create()
    cart_id = cart.id
    request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id
```

You probably should be checking the Cart actually exists, too.

```
carts = Cart.objects.filter(pk=request.session.get('cart_id'))  
# I'm not fully sure None is accepted here, use -1 if it's not. 

if carts:
    cart = carts[0]
else:
    cart = Cart.objects.create()
    request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id
```

And just use `cart` from then on.

Comment: Great, thanks very much, really helpful!

I'm now seeing 
`ValueError at /cart/add` 
`Cannot assign None: "CartItem.cart" does not allow null values.`

which I'm guessing is coming from my form?

Comment: Look in the code: you've got another `except Exception` clause when you try to retrieve the cart from the DB. Entering that clause causes the `cart` to be `None`. The Cart corresponding to the ID that's in your session probably does not exist in the DB. The Exception you're looking for is `Cart.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: Nice one, I see that now. Cheer for that, clarified things well for me!